# Python How to use if else in next iterator in one line to find the string after a particular string in a list

Tags: python

I have tried so many times but getting failed got syntax error

I want to do

```
next(x for x in ee if(re.findall(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b",x)))
```

Here I have one list

```
ee=['aa','kk','10.0.0.1','bb','192.3.45.11','cc','198.0.0.1',....]


I want only ip of 'kk' which is '10.0.0.1'  and ip of 'cc' '198.0.0.1'
```

So  i want to iterate and find next which match the ip and  remove the element from the list after getting the ip

in my above code it got the ip '10.0.0.1' but for the next ip of 'cc' ....how can I do it

I tried

```
next(x for x in ee ee.remove(x) if(re.findall(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b",x)))
```

but it give syntax error

```
>>> next(x for x in ee ee.remove(x) if(re.findall(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b",x)))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    next(x for x in ee ee.remove(x) if(re.findall(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b",x)))
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also tried

```
>>> next(x for x in ee if(re.findall(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b",x)): else: ee.remove(x))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    next(x for x in ee if(re.findall(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b",x)): else: ee.remove(x))
                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: yes done...I have make all my try all failed due to syntax error

Comment: I want only the first ip and the last ip not any ip between it may be the list has big many other ips are there in the list but I want the first and the  ip after cc or you may say the ip after cc I want and the first ip thats the requirement

Comment: yes then I want ['10.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1'] as these are just after cc and these are ip

Comment: I think you're mis-using `findall`.  You mean `fullmatch`.

Comment: simple ip after 'kk' and ip after 'cc' what I want

Comment: Why not just `ee[ee.index('cc') + 1]`?

Comment: if it is come after many other like ` ['cc','cv','ck''cj','198.0.0.1'] `

Comment: may I know why giving negetive vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to collect the IPs for the items specified in the input dictionary:

```
import re

# Initial list
ee = ['aa', 'kk', 'cv', '10.0.0.1', 'bb', '192.3.45.11', 'cc', '198.0.0.1', 'dd']

# Elements for which to collect the ip
ips = {'kk': None,
       'cc': None,
       }

for element in ee:
    if element in ips:
        # Start searching for ip from next position and pick first match
        for item in ee[ee.index(element) + 1:]:
            if re.fullmatch(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b", item):
                ips[element] = item
                break
print(ips)

# Remove found ips from list
ff = [element for element in ee if element not in ips.values()]
print(ff)
```

Comment: You are right. If it is only the IP values he is after, then a set would be perfect. I've made it a dictionary to provide also the mapping between element and its IP

Comment: I just realized, it makes perfect sense then :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why RE is in play here as it's just a matter of enumerating the list and checking against a set of possible values. For example:

```
MATCH = {'kk', 'cc'}

def is_valid_ip(s): # not strictly valid for all IP address formats
    return len(t := s.split('.')) == 4 and all(map(str.isdigit, t))

ee = ['aa', 'kk', '10.0.0.1', 'bb', '192.3.45.11', 'cc', '198.0.0.1']
ips = []
for i, e in enumerate(ee):
    if e in MATCH:
        for s in ee[i+1:]:
            if is_valid_ip(s):
                ips.append(s)
                break
ee = [e for e in ee if not e in ips]
print(ee)
print(ips)
```

**Output:**

```
['aa', 'kk', 'bb', '192.3.45.11', 'cc']
['10.0.0.1', '198.0.0.1']
```

Comment: He specified in the comments that other letters might be between searched element and the IP and in that case this will not work

Comment: @DanConstantinescu Thank you for interpreting the OP's question. Very helpful